# Randomly reshuffle words order in string

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a larger data frame consisting of texts where I want to reshuffle the order of words in each string randomly.

To give you a concrete exampleMy data looks somehow like the data below:

```
library(stringi)
require(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)

n <- 100
df <- data.frame(id = 1:n,
                 text = rep(stri_rand_lipsum(n)))

# Some preprocessing
df <- df %>%
  mutate(text = tolower(text),
         text = gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", text))
```

I want to reshuffle word order at random in each string found in the variable `text`.

I found several ways how to reshuffle each letter, but not any ways of how to reshuffle word's order randomly. Does anybody know how to do it? An important factor is that my data consists of millions of rows, thus, the approach need to be suitable for larger data sets as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `strsplit` the whole string with space `" "` as the delimiter. Then use `sample` on these individual words to generate random order, and `paste` them back into one string. I guess we should directly assign the result into a new column instead of using `mutate` if we are aiming for efficiency. However, I'm not sure how efficient my code is.

```r
df$random_text <- sapply(strsplit(df$text, " "), \(x) paste(sample(x), collapse = " "))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Worked perfectly, and also with an n = 10000000

Comment: I think this makes sense as long as it can run in a reasonable time. A quick performance win would be to replace `sapply()` with `vapply()` as you know the output will be `character(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

If performance is a factor try `data.table` and `stri_split`

```
library(data.table)
library(stringi)

setDT(df)

set.seed(42)

df[, text := paste(sample(stri_split(text, regex=" ")[[1]]), collapse=" "), 
  by = id]

# optional
setDF(df)
```